# how do i tell the user to re enter an integer below 3?

Tags: java

If the user enters anything above 3, I want them to re-enter a new integer. After they enter a new integer below 3, I want that new integer to go through the `if` statements again. Entering 0 will terminate the application.

Here's what I got:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("choose between 1, 2, or 3");
        System.out.println("enter 0 to exit");

        int i = sc.nextInt();
        do {
            if (i == 1){
                System.out.println("hi");
            }else if (i == 2){
                System.out.println("hello");
            }else if (i == 3){
                System.out.println("howdy");
            }else if (i > 3){
                System.out.println("invalid");
                //??? Make The User Enter A New Integer
            }
        } while (i != 0);

        if (i == 0){
            System.out.println("goodbye");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to just put the `int i = sc.nextInt();` inside the loop. This will repeat the program until the user terminates it by entering `0`.

```java
public class Testing3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {

            System.out.println("choose between 1, 2, or 3");
            System.out.println("enter 0 to exit");

            int i = sc.nextInt();

            if (i == 1){
                System.out.println("hi");
            }else if (i == 2){
                System.out.println("hello");
            }else if (i == 3){
                System.out.println("howdy");
            }else if (i > 3){
                System.out.println("invalid");
                //??? Make The User Enter A New Integer
            }
        } while (i != 0);

        // This if statement is unnecessary since `i == 0` will always be true here
        if (i == 0){
            System.out.println("goodbye");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (i > 3){
  i = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Please get rid of the second check:

```
do {} 
while (i != 0);
       if (i == 0){
           System.out.println("goodbye");
       }
```

If the condition to leave the loop is "if i equals 0", the second condition (i==0) does not make sense.